# How to programmatically open the modal dialogue box for link toolbar button?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In an instance of TinyMCE I would like to programmatically open the modal dialogue box for toolbar button 'link'.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

All you need to to this is to call the following javascript

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceAdvLink');
```

Comment: and also if you can help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338173/adding-html-class-to-tinymce-td-element). Thanks

Comment: if this solved your problem you should accept it :) (i'll have a look at your other question soon)