# Adding html class to tinymce td element

Tags: html, class, tinymce, addition

:)

It is my second post here in stackoverflow and got happy with the results of my first question. Anyway, I already have a working tinymce toolbar with a re-designed appearance. In achieving this I have used jQuery to add classes to the toolbar elements.

But in some way isn't it better if upon initializing the toolbars the classes are also added..

let's say:
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,"

currently: (the one that i have now)

- initiate tinymce
- find elements add class while there are elements

Result:

```
   <td class="first"> (*save elements here) </td>
   <td class="last"> (*newdocument elements here) </td>
   <td class="separator"> (*separator element here) </td>
   <td class="first"> (*bold elements here) </td>
   <td class="center"> (*italic elements here) </td>
   <td class="center"> (*underline elements here) </td>
   <td class="last"> (*strikethrough elements here) </td>
```

what I want to achieve:
 - initiate tinymce and add classes (*the result would be the same)

wouldn't it be faster this way?
I have been tracing the codes of tinymce but with my inexperience in coding makes it more harder for me... Anyone out there who knows the answer to my problem.. Please help me.. thank you and more power... :)

Comment: i am sorry, but i do not unsderstand what you desire here

Comment: the result is the tinymce toolbar buttons

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use the configuraton setting [editor_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_css).